# Java SimpleDateFormat am/pm

Tags: java, parsing, date-format, simpledateformat

I get an Date with format: MM-dd-yy hhmma zzz. The problem is that i only get an A for AM or P for PM. How can I parse a string with that format to a date object?

- Alex

Comment: what about some more information? what means "only an A for AM or P for PM"?

Comment: Can you put the format in which u receive the date string?

Comment: It works on my computer. Output : "05-21-13 0228PM CEST". My code is System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yy hhmma zzz").format(new Date()));

Comment: only means an 'A' which stands for AM, the same for 'P' for PM. For example: 05-21-13 0228P EDT

Answer (score 5):

Use this 'a'

example: MM-dd-yy hhmma a;

Visit http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 2):

This pattern is working for me:

### dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a

It prints the information in this format:
12-02-2016 03:50:07 PM

Answer (score 1):

Simple, do a string replace of A->AM/P->PM before parsing. SimpleDateFormat does not support A/P for AM/PM.

Comment: You could implement your own DateFormat..but that seems a tad excessive.

Answer (score 0):

dd-**MM**-yyyy (**MM-stands for month**). Please do not use MM in the time section of the DATE TIME hh:**MM**:ss.

> For example. It will display the date '15-**02**-2017 12:12:05'  as
>   '15-02-2017 12:**02**:05' instead of 12:12:05. Month replaced in the place of minutes.

- hh - stands for 12 hours time format
- HH - stands for 24 hours time format

it is best to use 12 hours time format with a '**hh:mm a**' to give clear picture on whether it is **'AM/PM**'